# PHP Glob - Return folder name

Tags: php, glob

I'm using `glob()` to parse through XML files stored on my server with the code below...

```
$files = glob('/home/website/dataupload/*.{xml}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $file) {
  // ...
}
```

The files are stored within two subdirectories following 'dataupload' and I'm trying to return the name of the first as a variable. For example, the structure could be like so...

```
/home/website/dataupload/brand-here/file-type/fileone.xml
```

I'm not concerned about the second directory ('file-type'), but need to be able to return the first directory ('brand-here') as a variable, such as `$brandName`.

Is this possible to do, and if so, may I receive assistance in making this happen please?

Comment: Please show us some effort. What actually have you tried to solve your issue?

Comment: Hey there, Zerkms! Honestly, I didn't know where to start so I've been searching around for the answer on Google. I apologize if that isn't what you expected to hear, but it's the truth. I'll continue to look around of course, but was hoping one of the great minds here could toss me a helping hand. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using the following code. It may not be the best way to do it, but it's how I got it working!

```
function recursiveGlob($dir, $ext) {
  foreach ($globFiles as $file) {
    $brandpath = dirname(dirname($file));
    $brandname = substr( $brandpath, strrpos( $brandpath, '/' )+1 );
  }
}

recursiveGlob('/home/website/dataupload', 'xml');
```

It works great, and while I'm sure it could've been done differently, it serves it's purpose! :-)